python yaml formatting - preserving new lines and indentation
I'm trying to read a structured YAML file and write it back out to another file after updating some entries (both keys and values may be modified).
However, I specifically want to maintain the newlines and original structure of the file.
The output file must:

maintain the order or the elements for both keys and values
preserve the new lines for lists (i.e. each element must start on a new line)
part of the lists should not break to new lines- like "description" and "nicknames" in the example file

Currently I use ruamel to process the data, like so:
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

with open('inputfile.yaml', 'r') as f1:
    data = yaml.load(f1)

with open('outputfile.yaml', 'w') as f2:
    yaml.dump(data, f1)

Suppose for example I have this inputfile.yaml:
- { "fruits_basket": [
  { "name": "Strawberry",
    "type": "fruit",
    "custom_labels": [
        { "x": "cereal", "a_value": "delicious"},
        { "b": "factory", "b_value": ["Vitamin C", "Manganese"]},
        { "c.d": "origin", "a_value": "Canada"},
        { "description": 
            [
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "small"},
                ],
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "custom"},
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "banana",
    "type": "fruit",
    "custom_labels": [
        { "x": "cerial", "a_value": "delicious"},
        { "b": "factory", "b_value": ["Vitamin B6", "Magnezium"]},
        { "c.d": "origin", "a_value": "Canada"},
        { "description": 
            [
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "big"},
                ],
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "custom"},
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
]
}


- { "smaller": [
  { "field": "six1",
    "header" : "strings",
    # Some comment descriptor
    "body": "formatted",
    "more_lists": [
      { "proportions":"large", "costruction_list": ["a", "b", "c"]},
      { "avatars": "a_list", "nicknames": 
        [
          ["a", "b", "c"],
          ["bruno", "mars", "rocks", "and", "this", "is", "a", "very", "long", "list", "not", "considering", "maximun", "width"]
        ]
      },
      { "number_of_players", "10"}
    ]
  },
  { "field": "citrus",
    "header" : "strings",
    # Some comment descriptor
    "body": "pre-formatted",
    "more_lists": [
      { "proportions":"large", "costruction_list": ["d", "a", "b"]},
      { "avatars": "a_list", "nicknames": 
        [
          ["c", "a", "b"],
          ["gotta", "take", "it", "to", "the", "other", "side","think", "of", "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit,", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua"]
        ]
      },
      { "number_of_players", "15"}
    ]
  },
  { "field": "zeta",
    "header" : "cars",
    # Some comment descriptor
    "body": "pre-formatted",
    "more_lists": [
      { "proportions":"large", "costruction_list": ["z", "j", "l", "k"]},
      { "avatars": "a_list", "nicknames": 
        [ 
          ["z", "j", "l", "k"],
          ["gotta", "take", "it", "to", "the", "other", "side", "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit,", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua"]
        ]
      },
      { "number_of_players", "20"}
    ]
  },
]
}

I want the resulting outputfile.yaml to be:
- { "fruits_basket": [
  { "name": "Strawberry",
    "type": "fruit",
    "custom_labels": [
        { "x": "cereal", "a_value": "delicious"},
        { "b": "factory", "b_value": ["Vitamin C", "Manganese"]},
        { "c.d": "origin", "a_value": "Canada"},
        { "description": 
            [
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "small"},
                ],
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "custom"},
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "banana",
    "type": "fruit",
    "custom_labels": [
        { "x": "cerial", "a_value": "delicious"},
        { "b": "factory", "b_value": ["Vitamin B6", "Magnezium"]},
        { "c.d": "origin", "a_value": "Africa"},
        { "description": 
            [
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "big"},
                ],
                [
                    { "notice1": "warning", "attribute": "multiple"},
                    { "notice2": "info", "attribute": "custom"},
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
]
}


- { "smaller": [
  { "field": "six1",
    "header" : "strings",
    # Some comment descriptor
    "body": "formatted",
    "more_lists": [
      { "proportions":"large", "costruction_list": ["a", "b", "c"]},
      { "avatars": "a_list", "nicknames": 
        [
          ["a", "b", "c"],
          ["bruno", "mars", "rocks", "and", "this", "is", "a", "very", "long", "list", "not", "considering", "maximun", "width"]
        ]
      },
      { "number_of_players", "22"}
    ]
  },
  { "field": "citrus",
    "header" : "strings",
    # Some comment descriptor
    "body": "pre-formatted",
    "more_lists": [
      { "proportions":"large", "costruction_list": ["d", "a", "b"]},
      { "avatars": "a_list", "nicknames": 
        [
          ["c", "a", "b"],
          ["gotta", "take", "it", "to", "the", "other", "side","think", "of", "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit,", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua"]
        ]
      },
      { "number_of_players", "15"}
    ]
  },
  { "field": "zeta",
    "header" : "cars",
    # Some comment descriptor
    "body": "pre-formatted",
    "more_lists": [
      { "proportions":"large", "costruction_list": ["z", "j", "l", "k"]},
      { "avatars": "a_list", "nicknames": 
        [ 
          ["z", "j", "l", "k", "a", "b", "c"],
          ["gotta", "take", "it", "to", "the", "other", "side", "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit,", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua"]
        ]
      },
      { "number_of_players", "20"}
    ]
  },
]
}

I've already checked the ruamel docs
and several Stack Overflow questions like

How can I insert linebreak in YAML with ruamel.yaml?

Using ruamel.yaml, how can I make vars with NEWLINEs be multiline without quotes

python yaml update preserving order and comments


I've tried multiple config options for ruamel such as:
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.compact(seq_seq=True, seq_map=True)
yaml.indent(mapping=6, sequence=4, offset=0)
yaml.width = 2048

And different typ values for the ruamel dumper such as:
yaml = YAML(typ="safe")
yaml = YAML(typ="unsafe")
yaml = YAML(typ="full")
yaml = YAML(pure=True)

However, no matter what I try, I can't seem to keep the newlines and structure of the original file.
How can I do that?

IIRC the documentation on ruamel.yaml states it tries to preserve block structured YAML. Comments ( spurious newlines are stored as comments) within flow style mappings and sequences are currently not preserved.
This is not because it is impossible to preserve these, but it will require extra work to, as the mechanism to attach the comment information, does so primarily on the basis of the preceding key c.q. element index, and has no provision for doing so to the flow style mapping/sequence indicator.
